# Enable --no-index by default in pip configuration

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way to set `--no-index` as default behaviour when installing packages with `pip` (both for Windows and Unix)?

Even though this configuration seems to work...

```
# /home/myaccount/.config/pip/pip.conf or C:\Users\MyAccount\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini
[global]
find-urls = 
    /path/to/folder1
    /path/to/folder2
no-index = true
```

I'm not able to find a reference of it in [pip configuration](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/) doc.
Am I doing it right?

NOTE: I'm working offline and I don't want to add the extra-burden of a local server repository. I'm just installing offline packages by setting `find-urls` configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Any* command-line option can be set using the configuration file, following some simple rules to map the switch to a name in the configuration file.

This is explained in the [*Naming* section of the *Configuration* chapter](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#naming):

> The names of the settings are derived from the long command line option.
>
> As an example, if you want to use a different package index (`--index-url`) and set the HTTP timeout (`--default-timeout`) to 60 seconds, your config file would look like this:
>
> ```ini
> [global]
> timeout = 60
> index-url = https://download.zope.org/ppix
> ```

Since `--no-index` is a boolean flag switch, the [*Boolean options* section](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#boolean-options) in the same chapter explains how to give such switches a value in the configuration file:

> Boolean options like `--ignore-installed` or `--no-dependencies` can be set like this:
>
> ```ini
> [install]
> ignore-installed = true
> no-dependencies = yes
> ```

Using `no-index = true` is *exactly* how you'd use that setting in a config file. Putting it in the `[global]` section means it'll apply to all your `pip` commands.

Because command-line options map directly to names in the config file using these simple rules, the configuration chapter doesn't have to cover every single possible config option.